# Angular, store-select with http get

Tags: angular, httpclient, ngrx-store

i would like to guard a route and do the following:

- check if user is in ngrx-store
- if user is in store return true at canActivate
- if not make an http-get and receicve user
- if user gets back, store it in store and return true on canActivate
- if 401, return false

Here is what i got so far:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.select(selectUser).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => {
        if (!!user) {
          return true;
        }

        return this.authService.getUser$()
          .pipe(
            map(user => {
              this.store.dispatch(addUser({user: user}));
              return true;
            })
          )
      })
    );

  }
}
```

Error:

```
Type 'Observable<true | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.
```

Problem is that return this.authService... returns an Observable which results in
Observable<Observable>.

How can i untie this knot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        if (!!user) {
          return true; // Returns a boolean - OK
        }

        return this.authService.getUser$()
          .pipe(
            map(user => {
              this.store.dispatch(addUser({user: user}));
              return true; // Returns an observable of a boolean - Not OK
            })
          )
```

Replace with switchMap :

```js
    return this.store.select(selectUser).pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap(user => {
        if (!!user) {
          return of(true);
        }

        return this.authService.getUser$()
          .pipe(
            map(user => {
              this.store.dispatch(addUser({user: user}));
              return true;
            })
          )
      })
    );
```